# Generating hidden fields iterating through IEnumerable<SelectListItem>

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc

How to make it work without hard coding.

```
@foreach (var item in Model.Items)
{   
   //not working - it's assigning blank value
   @Html.HiddenFor(o => o.ItemIds, new { @value = item.Value.ToString() })
   //working
   @Html.Hidden("ItemIds", item.Value);
}
```

Comment: you can try and use reflection.

Comment: I tried to keep a break point, the value is getting retrieved but not assigned.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could change your `Model.Items` declaration from an `IEnumerable` to an `List`, then reference your item via the index like so:

```
@Html.HiddenFor(o => o.Items[Model.Items.IndexOf(item)].Value)
```